# Reading and writing binary data of dynamic sizes question

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I am trying to read data from a file in binary mode and manipulate that data.

```
 try:
  resultfile = open("binfile", "rb")
 except:
  print "Error"
 resultsize = os.path.getsize("binfile")
```

There is a 32 byte header which I parse fine then the buffer of binary data starts.  The data can be of any size from 16 to 4092 and can be in any format from text to a pdf or image or anything else.  The header has the size of the data so to get this information I do

```
contents = resultfile.read(resultsize)
```

and this puts the entire file into a string buffer.  I found out this is probably my problem because when I try to copy chunks of the hex data from "contents" into a new file some bytes do not copy correctly so pdfs and images will come out corrupted.

Printing out a bit of the file string buffer in the interpreter yields for example something like "%PDF-1.5\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1 0 obj\r\n" when I just want the bytes themselves in order to write them to a new file.  Is there an easy solution to this problem that I am missing?

Here is an example of a hex dump with the pdf written with my python and the real pdf:

```
25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 35 0D 0D 0A 25 B5 B5 B5 B5 0D 0D 0A 31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0D 0D 0A

25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 35 0D    0A 25 B5 B5 B5 B5 0D    0A 31 20 30 20 6F 62 6A
```

It seems like a 0D is being added whenever there is a 0D 0A.  In image files it might be a different byte, I don't remember and might have to test it.
My code to write the new file is pretty simple, using contents as the string buffer holding all the data.

```
        fbuf = contents[offset+8:size+offset]
        fl = open(fname, 'a')
        fl.write(fbuf)
```

This is being called in a loop based on a signature that is found in the header.  Offset+8 is beginning of actual pdf data and size is the size of the chunk to copy.

Comment: You can call `resultfile.read()` to read the whole file.

Comment: `resultfile.read()` will return the entire contents of the file as a string.  Is there a reason you're grabbing the size first?

Comment: No reason, I just didnt know read() will return the entire file.

Comment: What you are doing should work. Post a complete example of reading and writing the file contents so we can understand what the problem is.

Comment: Made an edit to show what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your output file in binary mode, as you do your input file. Otherwise, newline characters may get changed. You can see that this is what happens in your hex dump: `0A` characters (`'\n'`) are changed into `OD 0A` (`'\r\n'`).

This should work:

```
input_file = open('f1', 'rb')
contents = input_file.read()

#....
data = contents[offset+8:size+offset] #for example

output_file = open('f2', 'wb')
output_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed the mode to "ab" and it works fine.  Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: @day break: If you found this answer helpful, you should "accept" it as the correct answer by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The result you get *is* "just the bytes themselves". You can write() them to an open file to copy them.

"It seems like a 0D is being added whenever there is a 0D 0A"

Sounds like you are on windows, and you are opening one of your files in text mode instead of binary.